# jquery fires multiple identical times on $(document).on

Tags: jquery

Jquery - this event:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".removeLink", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-link-id");
        $.post(
            "/Customization/DeleteCustomLink/" + id,
            function (resultData) {
                $("#frontEndPortalContainer").html(resultData);
            });
        return false;
    });
```

on this html (simplified - its actually a list of table input fields with this delete link)

```
<table>
<tr>
  ... <a href="javascript:;" class="removeLink" data-link-id="0">Remove</a>
</tr>
<tr>
  ... <a href="javascript:;" class="removeLink" data-link-id="1">Remove</a>
</tr>
```

I get 2 events occur when one link is clicked. It is 2 events on the same link. I only want the one event. With 4 links i get 4 calls to the event etc

I need $(document).on() or similar because it must 'rebind' to the newly ajax retrieved whole table html as a result of this delete (or my add table row button)

How can I restrict the event to just one?

answer see below in comments - whole javascript was in fact being repeated in a MVC view

Comment: Delegating events is great, but you should delegate to the nearest element which is static, my guess would be that there is a containing `div` or something which would be better. Delegating to the `document` means that every click will be inspected which will be slow - this is effectively what `live()` used to do and why it was deprecated. Secondly, do you have nested elements both having the `removeLink` class?

Comment: @user1444886 could you show your full html up to body?

Comment: I suspect you're executing that block of jquery more than once

Comment: popnoodles, that's wise, you are absolutely right - my colleague put the javascript into a MVC view which gets repeated - doh! many thanks